# How do I listen to changes for an ethereum address using websockets + RPC eth_subscribe method + postman

Tags: json-rpc, kovan, websocket

I am trying to listen for changes in a wallet balance on the Kovan testnet , so I have connected to a Kovan node using a node provider's websocket endpoint, I have no errors connecting, and no errors when sending the JSON to subscribe to an event, however when I use a faucet and drip into my wallet that I'm subscribed to, I get no response, however I get a response every second when I try to use JUST the "newHead" param instead of "logs" + address & topics, here is what I'm sending to initiate the subscription, the address included is the one I'm trying to listen for changes on:

[image: postman console]

Wondering what I'm doing wrong, also, I'm trying to do this WITHOUT web3 library.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `logs` will fire for contract's events, if no events are emitted then `logs` will not execute. External owned accounts never generate events so they will never execute `logs`. There's no ethereum api that provides updates to an address' balance. There are third party services to provide such service. Alternatively you can run your own address indexer.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for commenting, do you know which 3rd party services specifically address this problem?

Comment: When needed we used an indexer. I can't recommend any particular service.